# How to make a file descriptor blocking?

Tags: c, unix, file-io

Given an arbitrary file descriptor, can I make it blocking if it is non-blocking? If so, how?

Comment: what kind of file descriptor? different kinds of file descriptors act not the same when being set blocking....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its been a while since I played with C, but you could use the [fcntl()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) function to change the flags of a file descriptor:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// Save the existing flags

saved_flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);

// Set the new flags with O_NONBLOCK masked out

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, saved_flags & ~O_NONBLOCK);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the accepted method. Good answer and nice, terse approach to doing the fcntl with the ~O_NONBLOCK. :)

Answer (score 8):

I would expect simply non-setting the `O_NONBLOCK` flag should revert the file descriptor to the default mode, which is blocking:

```
/* Makes the given file descriptor non-blocking.
 * Returns 1 on success, 0 on failure.
*/
int make_blocking(int fd)
{
  int flags;

  flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
  if(flags == -1) /* Failed? */
   return 0;
  /* Clear the blocking flag. */
  flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
  return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) != -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm using this way but not wroking
void sendBytes(unsigned char bufferSize) 
{       
        int status;
  digitalWrite(TxEnablePin, HIGH);
 for (unsigned char i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++){
        serialPutchar (fd, comm_buf[i]) ;
       while(status == 0) 
       status = make_blocking(fd);
    }
  digitalWrite(TxEnablePin, LOW);
}

int make_blocking(int fd)
{
  int flags;

  flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
  if(flags == -1) /* Failed? */
   return 0;
  /* Clear the blocking flag. */
  flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
  return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) != -1;
}