# Is the fread function blocking?

Tags: c++, pipe, nonblocking, fdopen

I have the following code:

```
int buffer_max_size = 1024;
char* buffer = new char[buffer_max_size]
FILE* cout_file = fdopen(cout_pipe[0], "r");
while (fread( &buffer[0], sizeof(char),sizeof(char)*buffer_max_size, cout_file) != 0 )
{...}
```

cout_file is of type FILE* and is connected to a binary's stdout. 
 That binary outputs some text on its std_out at 5 sec intervals.

It seems that fread is blocking until the cout_file contains buffer_max_size bytes.. Is that normal?

I would like to be able to read what is in the pipe right now without blocking.. Is that possible?

Comment: unless you set it to non-blocking, it blocks.

Comment: How can I set it to non-blocking?

Comment: _'Is the fread function blocking?'_ That depends on the underlying device handle, and how you opened it probably ... You might also be interested in what [`poll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) actually offers.

Comment: Google it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914463/in-c-how-to-make-a-file-descriptor-blocking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want non-blocking I/O, use the OS's `read` and `fcntl` functions.

The `<stdio.h>` API (and also `<fstream>`) perform additional buffering and may automatically retry reads which end early (for example due to being interrupted by a signal), so they cannot be guaranteed to provide non-blocking I/O even if the underlying file descriptor is configured for it.

Not all OSes will use these POSIX names.  In that case your options are platform-specific code (for example, on Windows you would be using `ReadFile` and [`SetNamedPipeHandleState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), or using a wrapper library such as Boost ASIO to abstract the differences.  But make sure that your wrapper is designed to expose non-blocking behavior, otherwise it will cause the same pain as `<stdio.h>`