# How can I determine whether a socket is ready to read/write?

Tags: go

I'm using cgo do some network programming. I get native socket from `net.Conn` and use it in C, this socket is non-blocking, so I have to deal with error `E_AGAIN` every loop.

Is there any way in Go to determine whether a socket is ready to read/write like epoll? And how to use it?

Comment: Can't you first try cloning the FD (via `dup`) and then making it blocking (via `fcntl` with `~O_NONBLOCK`)? Both descriptors would refer to the same socket but have different options. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914520/720999).

Comment: Getting the FD from `net.Conn` already clones it with `dup`, so simply using `SetNonblock` should suffice.